# MRTG values mismatch snmwalk

Tags: mrtg

I have `MRTG` values show as 15Kbps, but when I check through `snmwalk` I got about 2G.

How can I fix this issue to let `MRTG` represent 2G on Graph as reported by `SNMP`?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing EXACTLY what you are querying, it is LIKELY that the snmpwalk returns 
absolute values, whereas MRTG returns "per second" values (ie. divided by time), or
the first derivative with respect to time. Can you confirm which you calculated?

Answer (score 0):

With a rate of 2G, you are likely hitting counter wraparound, when your 32bit SNMP counters are growing so fast that they overflow before you have time to read them.

You should make sure to do the following:

- Use 64bit counters, not 32bit.  This means using SNMPv2 and the HC counters; usually, adding the ":::::2" suffix to the Target works for this.  E.G.  3:public@router1:::::2
- Poll more frequently; maybe every 60s rather than every 5min
- Ensure your MaxBytes setting is correct, so that high values are not dropped

From the MRTG manual:

> **SNMPv2c**
>
> If you have a fast router you might want to try to poll the ifHC* counters. This feature gets activated by switching to SNMPv2c.
>   Unfortunately not all devices support SNMPv2c yet. If it works, this
>   will prevent your counters from wraping within the 5 minute polling
>   interval, since we now use 64 bit instead of the normal 32 bit.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>  Target[myrouter]: 2:public@router1:::::2
> ```

View the [MRTG documentation](https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-reference.en.html) for more information.